# ruby xml builder send text

Tags: ruby, xml, builder

I am trying to run though a program and send string literal value of variable to xml markup using xml.text! var_name. This var_name is having xml tag opening and closing, when i use the below code it covert < and > symbol into escape chars like < > respectively.

is it possible to achive my desired effect using builder

```
file = File.new("output.xml", "wb")
x = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => file, :indent => 2)
x.instruct!
var_name += "<tag1>value"
var_name += "</tag1>"
xml.text! var_name
```

actual output is:

```
&lt;tag1&gt;value&lt;/tag1&gt;
```

desired output:

```
<tag1>value</tag1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `xml` a typo? It should be `x.text!`, right? Did you try to use `x << var_name` instead of `x.text! var_name`? This method appends text without escaping markup

Comment: yes, I was typo in the question. Thank you for the solution. It worked for me.